# Проблема с циклом PHP

Tags: php

Мне нужно получить переменные $nameitem[0], $nameitem[1] и $nameitem[2], но почему-то когда заканчивается цикл while, единственная переменная, что остаётся это $nameitem[2] (остальные становятся пустыми). Я даже понимаю, что дело в особенности цикла while, но не знаю как это исправить и получить все переменные.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
for ($j = 0 ; $j < 3 ; ++$j)
{
$nameitem[$j] = $row[$j];
};
}
```

Comment: сделайте `array_push($nameitem, $row[$j])`. а вообще у вас страння конструкция и непонятно зачем вы так делаете

Comment: Зачем вообще использовать while? Просто получи данные по запросу в свой $row; Далее цикл у тебя не верный $nameitem = []; for ($j = 0 ; $j < 3 ; $j++)
{
$nameitem[$j] = $row[$j];
} И вообще зачем просто не присвоишь $nameitem = $row;

Comment: >И вообще зачем просто не присвоишь $nameitem = $row;
Потому что это не работает (как и буквально все ответы, которые мне дали). В таком случае я получаю только первую из 3 переменных. Честно говоря, я уже задал такой же вопрос на других форумах и я до сих пор не получил ответа, который бы работал. Удивлён, что у всех такое же низкое понимание PHP, как у меня.

Comment: Какой вопрос - такие ответы.
Потому что, надо задавать по нормальному вопрос и давать данные, какие вошли и какие надо

Comment: Ок, сейчас напишу подробнее. У меня в базе данных есть три товара, мне нужно получить их названия и записать в отдельные переменные. То есть должно в итоге получится три переменные с названиями товаров, но дело в том что в том коде, что я запостил, если выйти из цикла while, то будет заполнена только 3 переменная. Если же забить на цикл, то он запоминает только первую переменную. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно зачем так усложнять..зачем столько циклов
Есть готовая функция и бери первых 3 элемента или сколько ты там хочешь

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$a = array_slice($row,0,3);
```